# jdbcDatatable id possible values

Tags: iccube

In the `schema.icc-schema` schema definition xml file, in the `jdbcDatatable` tag there is an `id` attribute which looks like a serial number (3362e2cc-a588-492a-af9a-ea3b0e788ec4 in my case).

This id is used later in a `multiLevelDimension` tag to identify the table source via the `dataTableId` tag.

Is the id any arbitary string, or has it to conform to a special format? In other worlds, may I use an id like "foodmart-store" or "foodmart.store", to ease the migration of a Mondrian scheme into a icCube schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any format as long as it is unique (better within the schema).